# generate the json file from snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I generated the json file from snowflake table but column order in Json file is not same as select  query. It is reorder based on alphabetical order of column name. Please suggest how I can keep column order same in json file.

I have followed the following steps in given link as I have similar requirement.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Generating-a-JSON-Dataset-using-Relational-Data-in-Snowflake

Comment: Based on the JSON standard it "...does not assign any significance to the ordering of name/value pairs". This means if you do order name/value pairs, anything that processes the JSON including Snowflake is free to rearrange arrange them arbitrarily. https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake does not guarantee the order of the key pairs (*but usually orders them alphabeticall*y).

TO_JSON:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_json.html#usage-notes

> The order of the key-value pairs in the string produced by TO_JSON is
> not predictable.

It's the same for OBJECT_CONSTRUCT:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html

> The constructed object does not necessarily preserve the original
> order of the key-value pairs.

If you want them in a specific order (why do you need it?), then you can build the JSON manually:

```
select object_construct('a',a,'b',b) auto,
'{ "b":' || b || ', "a": ' || a || '}' manual 
from values (2,1) t(a,b);
```